# Grammatical construction vs. grammar construction

Tags: adjectives, nouns

Is it acceptable to use "grammar construction" instead of "grammatical construction" in the sense of "a group of words that form a constituent of a sentence and are considered as a single unit"?

Comment: I'm not saying "a grammar construction" is inherently ungrammatical (I certainly don't think it is), but [it's not common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+grammar+construction%2Ca+grammatical+construction&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20grammatical%20construction%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: ...you might also consider the related situation regarding [***electric / electrical connection***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+electric+connection%2Cthe+electrical+connection&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20electric%20connection%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20electrical%20connection%3B%2Cc0), but with *that* word-pair I'd be pretty sure many instances of the shorter form (and very few of the longer form) would be for *figurative / metaphoric* (i.e. - an energising / exciting connection / relationship between two people).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The word **grammar** is an uncountable noun which is used to describe
>   the structure of a language and the way in which linguistic units such
>   as words, phrases, and  clause are combined to make sentences (which
>   have a meaning).

You can find units of grammar being described as **grammar construction**.

At first glance it might seem wrong to use a noun  (grammar) to describe a construction.

**BUT** We are looking at the **function** of words rather than what part of speech they are, and so we can use the word grammar as an adjective.

**EX. grammar book, grammar question**, and **grammar construction**. Here the word grammar precedes the noun it adds information about and therefore acts as an adjective.

The word **grammatical** is an adjective which can be used to describe or tell us whether a word, phrase, clause or sentence follows the rules of grammar.

Ex. grammatical construction

grammatically can also be an adjective serving as a **complement.**

Ex The sentence is grammatical. **sentence=grammatical**

I hope that helps.